# Searching for multiple kinds of tags at once using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use `find_all()` to get all of the instances of several tag types (I don't care about class), in order, for a bit of soup using bs4.

I want to do something like this:

```
soup.find_all('p','a','span','b')
```

In this case, if I had two `p` tags then a `b` tag, I would want the command to return those three, in order, despite the fact that there were no `a` or `span` tags.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, [you can pass a list](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) of tag names to `find_all()` and it will look for all of them:

```
soup.find_all(['p', 'a', 'span', 'b'])
```